# How to execute code from txt file

Tags: java

I need to use a `.txt` file to excute the following code from text file. I am having trouble using the Scanner in File. `b.txt` has the following text input in it:

40.3 35.8 29.6 45 17.8 19.2 38.6 31.5 27.8 39.9  ...

Can anyone please help me to troubleshoot this issue?

```
  import java.util.*;
  public class arrayLabFirst
  {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  double[ ] temperatures = new double[10];
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(“b.txt”)); 

  temeratures[]=infile.hasNext();


  for (int index = 0; index < temperatures.length; index++)
  temperatures[index] = input.nextDouble();

  printArray(temperatures);
  System.out.println("The average of the temperatures entered is: " + arrayAverage(temperatures));
  System.out.println("The greatest temperature is: " + greatest(temperatures));
  System.out.println("The lowest temperature is: " + lowest(temperatures));
  }
  public static void printArray(double[] temperatures)
  {
  for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
  System.out.println(temperatures[i]);
  }
  public static double arrayAverage(double[] temperatures)
  {
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
  sum += temperatures[i];
  return sum/temperatures.length;
  }
  public static void countDays(double[] temperatures)
  {
  int aboveCount = 0;
  int belowCount = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
  {
  if (i > 32)
    aboveCount++;
  else
    belowCount++;
  }
 System.out.println("number of days above freezing: " + aboveCount);
 System.out.println("number of days below freezing: " + belowCount);
 }
public static double greatest(double[] temperatures)
{
int maxIndex = 0;
for (int index = 1; index < temperatures.length; index++)
  if (temperatures[maxIndex] < temperatures[index])
  maxIndex = index;

return temperatures[maxIndex];
}
public static double lowest(double[] temperatures)
{
  int minIndex = 0;
  for (int index = 1; index < temperatures.length; index++)
  if (temperatures[minIndex] > temperatures[index])
  minIndex = index;

  return temperatures[minIndex];
}
}
```

Comment: u need to read text from text file then u can execute. but before that show sample of you text file.

Comment: why do you think that `temeratures[]=infile.hasNext();` would work?

Comment: 40.3 35.8 29.6 45 17.8 19.2 38.6 31.5 27.8 39.9

Comment: does this code even compile?

Comment: 40.3 35.8 29.6 45 17.8 19.2 38.6 31.5 27.8 39.9  < That is my sample file. I think temeratures[]=infile.hasNext(); should work because, I used infile.hasNext() to print the contents of the array.

Comment: No it doesnot compile.

Comment: You can't assign a `boolean` value to an array of `double`.  The code you posted will not compile.

Comment: So, your problem has nothing to do with your input file.  You should clean up your question to remove any mention of input or runtime issues and talk about the compile-time errors you are getting.

Comment: Can you please give me idea how it can be done?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the input file. I just donot know how to use all the doubles of my text file as array contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand all the negativity, but let me quickly explain what they're talking about.  You're using the method *hasNext()* on *inFile*, which returns a boolean value as to whether is has a "next" value.  In this case, it checks if there's a next double.  The issue was that you were assigning an array of doubles to that boolean value, which you **can't** do.

Here's what I got to work, using your code;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
public class arrayLabFirst
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        double[ ] temperatures = new double[10];
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("data.txt")); 
        for (int index = 0; index < temperatures.length; index++)
            if(inFile.hasNext())
                temperatures[index] = inFile.nextDouble();
            else
                continue;

        printArray(temperatures);
        System.out.println("The average of the temperatures entered is: " + arrayAverage(temperatures));
        System.out.println("The greatest temperature is: " + greatest(temperatures));
        System.out.println("The lowest temperature is: " + lowest(temperatures));

        inFile.close();
    }
    public static void printArray(double[] temperatures)
    {
        System.out.print("Input Array:\n[");
        for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(temperatures[i]);
            if(i < temperatures.length - 1)
            {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]\n");
    }
    public static double arrayAverage(double[] temperatures)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
            sum += temperatures[i];
        return sum/temperatures.length;
    }
    public static void countDays(double[] temperatures)
    {
        int aboveCount = 0;
        int belowCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
        {
            if (i > 32)
                aboveCount++;
            else
                belowCount++;
        }
        System.out.println("number of days above freezing: " + aboveCount);
        System.out.println("number of days below freezing: " + belowCount);
    }
    public static double greatest(double[] temperatures)
    {
        int maxIndex = 0;
        for (int index = 1; index < temperatures.length; index++)
            if (temperatures[maxIndex] < temperatures[index])
                maxIndex = index;

        return temperatures[maxIndex];
    }
    public static double lowest(double[] temperatures)
    {
        int minIndex = 0;
        for (int index = 1; index < temperatures.length; index++)
            if (temperatures[minIndex] > temperatures[index])
                minIndex = index;        

        return temperatures[minIndex];
    }
}
```